# Qt memory deallocation - delete of an object with QList of object pointers attribute - Avoid memory leak

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, qlist

I have a C++ program (developed in Qt) with the `GetVariablesRequest` class. This class has the attribute `getVariableData` (`QList` of pointers of the `GetVariableDataType` class).

```
class GetVariablesRequest
{
public:
    GetVariablesRequest();
    ~GetVariablesRequest();

    QList<GetVariableDataType*> getVariableData;
}

class GetVariableDataType
{
public:
    GetVariableDataType();
    ~GetVariableDataType();

    int x;
};
```

I use the class as reported below.

```
....
GetVariablesRequest* request = new GetVariablesRequest();

GetVariableDataType* type1 = new GetVariableDataType();
GetVariableDataType* type2 = new GetVariableDataType();
GetVariableDataType* type3 = new GetVariableDataType();
GetVariableDataType* type4 = new GetVariableDataType();

request->getVariableData[0] = type1;
request->getVariableData[1] = type2;
request->getVariableData[2] = type3;
request->getVariableData[3] = type4;
...
```

If I call the delete of the "request" variable (as reported below), is also the memory of the objects `type1`, `type2`, `type3` and `type4` deallocated correctly? Or only the memory of the `request` variable is deallocated?
Will I have a memory leak?

```
...
delete request;
```

I would avoid memory leak.

Comment: `QList<std::unique_ptr<GetVariableDataType>>` would avoid memory leak.

Comment: Yes,  you will have memory leaks. This is a typical result of a very common C++ problem called "Pointless Use Of Pointers". If, instead, `getVariableData` was a `QList<GetVariableDataType>`, then nothing needs to be `new`ed, or `delete`d, and it will be logically impossible to have a memory leak in that case.

Comment: I think in your case calling `qDeleteAll(*request); request->clear(); delete request;` will do the job.

Comment: Note that `request->getVariableData[0]` is UB, if your list has 0 elements, like in your example.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Using a QList<GetVariableDataType> is a problem in my program because I will have to change the entire software architecture of the program. Calling: qDeleteAll(*request); request->clear(); delete request; is something that I can try. How can I understand if this solution work? It's very difficult for me understanding if I have a memory leak or not.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. I imagine classes in your code to be more complex, and that what you posted is just a minimal working example. Take into account @Jarod42 suggestion: use smart pointers to avoid having to remember when and who should delete an object. To detect memory leaks at runtime, check out [valgrind (memcheck)](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html) (also [integrated](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-valgrind-overview.html)).
PS: Your question applies to all container types: look for "container of pointers" or "`std::vector` of pointers"...

Comment: Try running your program with `valgrind`. It can tell you if you have a memory leak.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I know `valgrind` and `memcheck`. My problem is that my embedded system doesn't have enoguh free memory to use it. I will need a clarification: if I call `qDeleteAll(getVariableData); getVariableData->clear();` inside `~GetVariablesRequest();`, is it enough to free the memory (calling the `delete request`)?

Comment: Yes, in fact, you do not need `getVariableData->clear()` because the destructor of the `QList` will take care of deleting all entries. You just add `qDeleteAll(getVariableData);` in `~GetVariablesRequest()`.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to summarize here the discussion we had in the comments that ultimately led to answering the question.

##### Container of pointers

A container of pointers (like `QList<element_type*>` or even `std::vector<element_type*>`) stores pointers and does not *own* or even care about the objects pointed to by the pointers themselves.

The destructor of a standard container takes care of clearing up the resources allocated by the container itself during its lifetime, nothing more.

Deleting the objects pointed to by the pointers inside the container is the responsibility of the calling code. This can be achieved by iterating on the container entries and by invoking the `delete` expression over each pointer. Since this is a common scenario for *Qt* developers, the library provides an helper method: `qDeleteAll()` [[doc]](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtalgorithms.html#qDeleteAll-1).

> Notice that qDeleteAll() doesn't remove the items from the container; it merely calls delete on them.

The previous sentence means that the elements of the container should be removed by *clearing* the container. Of course, if you invoke `qDeleteAll()` in `~GetVariablesRequest`, where you know the container will no longer be accessed before its deletion, you can avoid *clearing* the container.

##### Design issues

As other users have pointed out, it is not a good idea to store raw pointers in a container. If your application requirements are so that `GetVariableDataType` must be accessed through a pointer, it is better to use smart-pointers like `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`. The latter would be the proper one to use given that the container is taking ownership of the *pointed to* object.

[Examples on Live Compiler](https://onlinegdb.com/S_f7At57O)